# How to get I and Q components from echoes of a Chirp signal?

Tags: signal, phase

The Bandwidth of the signal is 10 MHz, the central frequency is 20 MHz, sampling frequency is 26.6 MHz.

So, if to get the Quadrature component I have to shift the signal of 90°, how do I get the phase of a signal with a changing phase such as the chirp?

Comment: You shift the LO by 90deg in the Q mixer not the RF signal

Comment: To my knowledge, I only have the RF data, stored as an array of values. But I'll try what you suggested

Comment: @Alessandro I and Q components are what you get by mixing an RF signal with a local oscillator.

Comment: I and Q are the outputs of 2 modulators (one with local RF - 0° phase, and the other with local RF - 90° phase).

Comment: Ok, thank you! Now I understand it perfectly!

Comment: See this as example  https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/admv4540.pdf

Comment: So, basically, I create 2 sine waves (one shifted by 90° with respect to the other) having a frequency of 20 MHz (I'm guessing) and I'll multiply them by the signal. Thank you!!

Comment: If the centre frequency of the RF is at 10MHz use that frequency as the LO. That will give a zero frequency IF with positive and negative sidebands. Since the sampling frequency 26.6MHz a 20MHz LO would be above Nyquist anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I made a mistake in the original post. The real central frequency is 20 MHz.

Comment: Note that mixing the incoming RF (or IF) frequency with two versions of the LO, with a 90 deg phase difference between them, is basic to radar and communications processing.  Whether that frequency is considered RF or IF depends on your point of view.  We may convert a 12 GHz signal down to 400 MHz I&Q, maybe in a couple of steps, for sampling.  The 400 MHz signals are called the IF.

Comment: IF your signal BW is 10MHz then why sample at 26.6Mhz for 15 to 25MHz Band signals?  You will must have group delay distortion in your filters

Comment: You seem to have some idea but lack the experience.  Although this is more effective at higher carrier frequencies for the same BW this will give you an idea how to do Chirp Radar.  https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1145166/